# how to solve 2nd order coupled equation by using python?

Tags: python, numpy, differential-equations, astronomy, odeint

I am trying to solve 2nd order coupled equation by `odeint`. I don't know how to pass two constant list `z0 and w0` but I tried here is my code.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

def cpld(z,w,r):
    a = 0
    E0 = -0.143

    v0 , v0div = z
    R0 , R0div = w
    dzdr =[v0div,(-2/r)*v0div+R0**2]
    dwdr =[R0div,2((-R0*E0)+R0*v0+(a/r))-(2/r)*R0div]
    return [dzdr,dwdr]

n = 100000
z0 = [2,0]
w0 = [2,0]
r = np.linspace(0,22*np.pi,n)
y = odeint(cpld,z0,r)

print('r =',r)
print('y =',y)
plt.plot(r,y)
plt.show()
```

[![][21]][12]

Comment: You have to "flatten" your two 2-d arrays into a single 4-d array.  See, for example, https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/CoupledSpringMassSystem.html, and Lutz Lehmann's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Start with

```
def cpld(u,r):
    v0 , v0div , R0 , R0div = u
```

and finish with

```
    return [*dzdr, *dwdr]
```

You will have to unpack the result of the numerical integration, which is a list of 4-dimensional state vectors, then analogously.

With all-purpose ODE solvers one has to translate the structured state of the model into a flat array for the solver, and wrap the rhs procedure with decoding/restructuring and encoding/flattening procedures if the derivatives computation is better organized inside the model.